# Rotate an image when page scrolls

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll

Say I have an image of a circle as my background image on a webpage how would I make it rotate clockwise as the page scrolls down and counter as it scrolls up? Im thinking maybe something like `-moz-transform: rotate(Xdeg)` with some kinda of script to change the value of X as the page scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do it with a background image, but maybe take a look at this jquery extension or at least how it's built:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/